# Why are election results presented by a geographic map instead of a cartogram map?

Tags: info-visualisation, maps

This morning (in Sweden) I woke up early to watch the 2012 presidential election in United States. I watched different news sources but all of them presented a geographical map of the results instead of cartogram results, giving the impression that Republican candidate had won the election by a landslide since more than half of the United States of America was painted red (image below taken from the 2008 election, as an example):

[image: Geographic map of the 2008 election]

As it turns out that is not the case. States that are smaller by area, but larger by population (and therefore electoral votes) have a greater impact of the result than what is visible on a geographical map.

There are alternatives, such as a demographic map or cartogram which display the area equal to importance. This gives a more correct visualization of the actual result than a geographic map:

[image: cartogram map of the 2008 election]

Still, what’s displayed on the news worldwide today is the geographic map. It may be that what we are seeing is an established convention, but the visualization fails and you need to explain to your consumers how to read the map. I think it would be more obvious to the consumer if a cartogram map were used.

So why are election results presented on a geographic map instead of a cartogram map?

---

<sup>Images from the article [Transforming the Electoral Map: Beyond Red and Blue](http://reason.com/blog/2012/10/30/the-electoral-map-beyond-red-and-blue)</sup>

Comment: It should not be weighted by population — it should be weighted by number of electors. Surprisingly, the two are *not* proportional.

Comment: @gerrit They are not? What's the deviation? i.e. How many votes you need to get elector vote in Florida differs from number of votes in Montana?

Comment: @BennySkogberg, it differs for a variety of reasons, googling gave me a table at [FairVote.org](http://archive.fairvote.org/index.php?page=985), dated but the principle is still the same. I recall reading that one reason the southern states are over-represented is that people used to vote "on behalf of their slaves", but I don't know if that is true and if it is still the reason for the skewed distribution today. I don't know the details.

Comment: @BennySkogberg the elector count is based on number of congressmen. *Every* state has exactly two senators, as the Senate is not based on population; the remainder of the electors *is* proportional to population, which is how the House of Representatives is allocated. So smaller states have proportionally more electors per person, but not by very much.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield That explains the figures sorting the states by population in decending order. Soon this comment line will be migrated to [Politics.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics)

Comment: @JonW As far as I know, nobody decided that :). To be more exact, it was an arbitrary decision by some designer and it just stuck.

Comment: @BennySkogberg when the US Constitution was written the states were much closer to being independent countries than political subdivisions of a single entity.  The system was designed to balance the desire of smaller states that each would have equal rank (as in the articles of confederation - the predecessor of the current constitution) to prevent a few of the largest states from being able to run everything to their benefit and that of the large states to have influence proportional to their population.

Comment: @BennySkogberg Per country MEP allocations are done in a way that gives smaller countries an influence larger than their raw population as a fraction of the EU would give them for similar reasons.  Assuming greater EU integration in the future this has the potential to cause friction similar to what the electoral college does in present day America; except that lacking a simple formula for allocations there is probably more room for fighting over what is or is not 'fair' than in the US system.

Comment: @DanNeely Thanx for your enlighted comments. In Europe we have a hard time only to determine what belongs to Europe and what doeasn't. Turkey is up for debate as well as the Ukraine. If that settles we need to have a independent European Goverment Bank making interest rate desicions based on economic reality and not locally expressed feelings from single countries. But we have 200 years up before Europe reach US maturity as a real union.

Comment: For those familiar with the election process, a map only having IA, FL and the other swing states would really be more helpful in improving information density. Florida can (and basically just did) easily sway the results. California, despite having more votes, almost certainly won't as it's more or less a 100% sure vote for Democrat

Comment: @BennySkogberg In addition to the above, most states will allocate all their electoral votes to one candidate - except Maine and Nebraska, which split theirs up.

Comment: @BenBrocka In theory, all we need to know is Ohio's vote  ;)

Comment: @JonW: Historically, "red" was considered very negative, so to avoid the appearance of bias, the major networks used a publicized quasirandom algorithm to determine which party would get which color each year. But in the 2000 elections, the colors became such a big part of the discourse -- "red state", "blue state", etc. -- that in subsequent elections, the networks decided to preserve the 2000 colors in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ruakh interesting. (TIL!) However that begs the question: Why did they ever use Red in the first place if they were aware of the negative connotations?

Comment: If you were to scale it, wouldn't you want to scale by electoral college votes and not population?

Comment: @JonW: America's national colors are red, white, and blue, and we have a mostly-two-party system, so I guess it just seemed perfect: red for one party, blue for the other, white for as-yet-unclear. Though I suppose they could have used red for as-yet-unclear, and white and blue for the parties? Clearly they didn't hire User Experience professionals to make these decisions for them. :-P

Comment: @ruakh White is ingrained into us as "nothing" [throughout childhood](http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/Connected-Kids-Coloring-Books_3.png), so it kind of had to go that way...

Comment: I think it would make more sense if you plotted colored dots for each electoral vote. Rhode Island would still be filled in, but 3 red dots in Montana would look suitably sparse.

Comment: I think your assumption is wrong: you're saying that using a geographic map forces us to explain to "consumers" why the democrat candidate won. I say that using the cartogram would force us to explain to most people who have no clue what a cartogram is why the map looks "stupid" and why they shouldn't giggle at it on FB or Twitter.

Comment: What I don't understand here is why would anyone look at a colored map starting from the premise that more area always means "more" in general.  If you use this general rule of thinking every time you look at a representation of something, you're whole life is a series of misunderstandings. This leads to things like: Greenland is then the same size as south American, Semi-Trucks are bigger therefore they must have more speed than a sports car, a 300 lb person gets twice as many votes as a 150 lb person...  etc.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UBgj-2LzuI&feature=player_embedded for some non-geographical maps of the US elections 2008

Answer (score 83, accepted):

People who turn on the TV on election night expect to see the map of their country and see which states voted which way. Those who actually follow the elections and have at least some very basic knowledge of what's going on, also know which are the important states to watch, and they can find them easily on the geographic map. Even those who aren't that involved are very familiar with the geographic outline of the US.

If a TV channel displayed the bottom map, people tuning in would be completely stumped as to why there's no map of the US, and instead there's a cartoon of a blue Batman flying to the left, wearing a red apron and sporting a huge erection.

No unprepared layman can understand the bottom map. Most viewers wouldn't even recognize it as a map of the US. These kind of tools are great for analysts or at least for people who know the logic behind the skewed display and can interpret it easily. But if you take the general population, a large percent of them wouldn't know that non-geographical maps even exist. Even if you provided a constant on-screen explanation (which would be extremely annoying and not really helpful in any case, as this is not something that can be explained in a brief footnote), by the time it would take for viewers them to find and read it, they would be long gone to a channel that does appear to know what the US looks like :).

Comment: Batman, capes, etc - ok - so I see it now that you say it, but man - you are...I dunno...that's special that is :-)

Comment: +1 for "cartoon of a blue Batman flying to the left, wearing a red apron and sporting a huge erection". Seriously - I think you're right, but it would be nice if the media would at least try to educate viewers and show the results in a more visual correct way.

Comment: Roger, ok, then it's best that I don't tell you what I see in the regular map :)

Comment: OMG! I see it now!  Kinda looks like he's spitting and wincing from a POW! or a WHAM!

Comment: Animation (morphing from the geographic map to the cartogram) along with a narrative voice over could explain it to the average viewer.

Comment: Kaz - at what point do you play the animation? Constantly in a loop? :) New people come all the time.

Comment: I think that what @Kaz suggests would be a nice way to show the connection between geography and "graphy". :)

Comment: @Kaz "Think of how stupid the average person is, and realize half of them are stupider than that." /G. Carlin/

Comment: I now keep misreading the question title as "why are erection results...". Gah.

Comment: So that's why Mercator is used.

Answer (score 32):

Interesting graphic - the US looks quite funny. But I think a geographic representation is still best way because of:

- The viewer is interested in what state has elected and which party. This is best shown in a geographical correct map as you are used to know where a state is situated.
- It is obvious, that the USA is shown. No need for explaining a strange shape, that could be the US.
- At a glance you see, that midwest of US is Republicans base and the coastal areas voted for the Democrats.
- The lower map is quite interesting, but I assume just a minor percentage of viewers will identify its meaning. Its too experimental to be common-sense. May be one could put the amount of presidential electors inside a state to show its importance.
- Numbers - how many presidential electors per state - are won for whom are best shown as numbers, because the pure number 272 matters. Or a pie chart, which is good for indicating more than a half.

edit: I found this one with numbers in the states.

[image]

Source: [telepolis](http://www.heise.de/tp/artikel/37/37959/1.html)

Comment: +1 for the numbers map. It makes is a bit easier for the eye than just red/blue coloring.

Comment: Note the difference desaturated colors can make; this map is much more pleasant to look at (not just because of the numbers) than the ultra-saturated maps in the question

Comment: If bigger numbers would have a more dominant color or thickness, maybe that would represent the importance of a state better.

Answer (score 24):

The point is that the map is intended as an at-a-glance throwaway space filler that does it's job simply and efficiently and for all viewers.

Of course, that's not to say there's no place for maps with more information, but there's no point in doing that unless you can provide a way for the user to interact with the map in a meaningful manner that allows them to easily take away information according to their interests.

So we get interactive maps like we see from Guardian data blog, NY Times and they have much more exploratory intent than the simple graphic.

There is a place for both, but I don't think there's a need to *mess* with the recognisable constants like country and state border shapes in order to try and artificially *force* the quick graphic into being an informative interactive graphic. It's not the correct way to go about it and you end up confusing (and therefore failing) rather than actually being informative.

Case in point: - here's the Guardian map of the same information - no throwaway map - this one is fully interactive - there's a small version on the home page today and there's [a full version linked](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/us-elections-2012/results/president) from it.

[image]

[image]

Then as Benny points out - you can drill down into your state of interest and really explore the local data *as well* as having the graphical representation of both local Rep/Dem split and size of lead indicated by height of county. Brilliant!

[image]

Comment: +1. It get's even better if you select a state and you see a 3D diagram where height represent population. That's really nice and gets to be informative.

Comment: For reference, I added a snapshot of that to my answer.

Comment: @Benny: Size of lead, not population.  Otherwise, Harris County (Houston) is way too short.

Comment: @dan04 Yeah, I saw that later when Roger posted the image. Looks strange though since "size of lead" isn't as informative as population imho. Still a better representation than just a plain map!

Answer (score 5):

The best map I have seen is by [Chris Howard](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/camelswithhammers/2012/11/coloring-the-electoral-map-by-district-population-density-and-partisan-split/).

*It combines population density and partisan lean using color*:

[image: Coloring the 2012 Electoral Map by County, Population Density, and Partisan Split]

Comment: +1 This is really really nice. Good visualization there! Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 3):

There is a half way house between the plain geographic map that lead's republicans to think they won (or should have won) because more of the map is red and the continuous cartogram featured in the question. This is the discontinuous cartogram where the sizes of the states is modified to represent the population (or number of electoral college votes, etc).

In this image the colours represent the unemployment rate while the size of the states represents the number of people in the state (year 2000 stats for any one who is really interested). I have an interactive version [here](http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver/www/cartogram/discontinous.html).

[image: 2000 Unemployment rate]

Comment: This is an interesting combination between geographic and informational, however it tends to lose it's impact for the smaller states where you get virtually no indication of the data because it takes up such a small amount of pixels.

Comment: That's because no one really cares about what N Dakota thinks :-)